# How to create 10 copies of the XML file, each with a different value of the td tag- PowerShell script

Tags: arrays, xml, powershell

I just started learning PowerShell (literally - just a week and completely from tutorials and materials online :)) so don`t be harsh on me)

I would appreciate help and how to do it because I am stuck at this point.. So I have this template file, I created 10 copies of it but I have no idea how to change both td tag values "." with different name for Title and Artist in each copy.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>.</td>
        <td>.</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is how far I got but I would appreciate some help/advice/explanation for correct further steps..

```bash
[xml]$File= get-content "\MyXMLFile.xml"
1..10 |% { Copy-Item "\MyXMLFile.xml" "MyXMLFile$_.xml"}

$copiedFiles =@(Get-ChildItem -Path "XmlFileFolder" | % Name)

$exampleNode = $File.SelectNodes("//td[1]")
                                      
$TitleNodeArray = @('aa', 'bb', 'cc', etc..) #but I have no idea how to go on from there ..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  this.

```
using assembly System 
using assembly System.Linq
using assembly System.Xml.Linq 

$inputFilename = "c:\temp\test.xml"

$xDoc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($inputFilename)
$tds = $xDoc.Descendants("td").Foreach([System.Xml.Linq.XElement])
$td0 = $tds[0]
$td1 = $tds[1]
Write-Host $xDoc
$newWords1 = @("abc1","def1","ghi1","jkl1","mno1","pqr1","stu1","vwx1","yz11","2341")
$newWords2 = @("abc2","def2","ghi2","jkl2","mno2","pqr2","stu2","vwx2","yz12","2342")

for($i = 0; $i -lt 10; $i++)
{
Write-Host $i $newWords1[$i]
   $td0.SetValue($newWords1[$i])
   $td1.SetValue($newWords2[$i])

   $xDoc.Save("c:\temp\testoutput" + $i + ".xml")
}
```

Comment: The for loop only needs three instruction to create 10 files.  The two SetValue statements and the Save.

Comment: Thank you @jdweng but this would create 10 copies with each copy having i.e "abc" as title and "efg" as Artist right? but what if I need a different name for each td tag in each copy? Can I create arrays of 10 title and 10 Artist names? But I don't know how to implement them in a  loop..

Answer (score 0):

hmm, I don't work much with xml but I know of one-way which uses `Select-Xml`.

```
(Select-Xml -Xml $File -XPath '//tr/td')[1].Node."#text" = 'title'
```

Where `[1]` is the indexed node, and `#text` being the value/text itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I can find and edit these td tags separately and one by one I was just thinking how to do it all in one go so to say.. like perhaps creating two arrays of 10 names but then what? :)

Comment: @levaRay, can you update your question with what you need. Guessing from our end won't help much if you don't provide a minimal reproducible example. I don't understand what you mean by creating 2 arrays of 10 names, then what? What?